# Cannot call perl script from Java

Tags: java, perl

When I'm trying to run a perl script from my main java application:

```
            try {
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(path+"\\script.pl");
                Process p = pb.start();     // Start the process.
                p.waitFor();                // Wait for the process to finish.
                System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
              } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

I get the following error (not a valid win32 app):

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\workspace\kepler\Alert_Handler\target\test-classes\script.pl": CreateProcess error=193, %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to run perl code in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751572/using-runtime-getruntime-exec-to-run-perl-code-in-java)

Comment: does the perl script work when you invoke it manually?

Comment: No mention of `PATHEXT` in that "duplicate"

Answer (score 1):

Unix uses the shebang line to indicate a file is executable, but Windows uses a different mechanism based on file extensions. The file extensions Windows considers executable are those enumerated by the `PATHEXT` environment variable. You can solve your program by altering your `PATHEXT` variable as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4727490/4241250).

Alternatively, you could explicitly specify you want to launch the script using `perl`.

```
new ProcessBuilder("perl.exe", path+"\\script.pl");
```

- ikegami

Answer (score 0):

Ok -- my mother-tongue isn't spanish but this

```
no es una aplicación Win32 válida
```

Seems to translate into "this isn't a valid Win32 application" so it seems under Windows you explicitly have  to start the Perl interpreter with the script as an arg. Something like:

```
new ProcessBuilder("perl.exe",path+"\\script.pl");
```

may be ?